# How to download file from url using python in the same format?

Tags: python, file, url, download

I have to download file, I see I can do it using "urllib2".

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(URL)
file=response.read()
```

But, I can't read line by line.

Here's what I tried:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(URL)
for line in response.read():
    #do stuff
```

All the file is one line.
The original file was split by new lines.

Can someone tell me how to change the file to be like the original one?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include sample data?

Comment: response = urllib2.urlopen('http://mirror1.malwaredomains.com/files/domains.txt')
for line in response.read():

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear, could you add example data *from the webpage you are opening*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split the output:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(URL)
lines=response.read().splitlines()
```